# Node.js - TypeError: res.json is not a function (working in some routes and not in others)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working in the MERN stack (Mongo, Express, React, Node) and running into an error in my API.

Here is my `plaid.js` file where one of my routes is throwing this error. Of course, I've removed all of my secret token variables but assume everything works until the res.json error (which it does).

```
        const express = require("express");
        const plaid = require("plaid");
        const router = express.Router();
        const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
        const keys = require("../../config/keys");
        const passport = require("passport");
        const moment = require("moment");
        const mongoose = require("mongoose");

        // Load Account and User models
        const Account = require("../../models/Account");
        const User = require("../../models/User");

        // Replaced my actual keys with empty strings for sake of this post
        const PLAID_CLIENT_ID = "";
        const PLAID_SECRET = "";
        const PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY = "";

        const client = new plaid.Client(
          PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
          PLAID_SECRET,
          PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY,
          plaid.environments.sandbox,
          { version: "2018-05-22" }
        );

        var PUBLIC_TOKEN = null;
        var ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
        var ITEM_ID = null;

        // @route POST api/plaid/accounts/add
        // @desc Trades public token for access token and stores credentials in database
        // @access Private
        router.post(
          "/accounts/add",
          passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
          (req, res) => {
            PUBLIC_TOKEN = req.body.public_token;

            const userId = req.user.id;
            const institution = req.body.metadata.institution;
            const { name, institution_id } = institution;

            if (PUBLIC_TOKEN) {
              client
                .exchangePublicToken(PUBLIC_TOKEN)
                .then(res => {
                  ACCESS_TOKEN = res.access_token;
                  ITEM_ID = res.item_id;

                  // Check if account already exists for specific user
                  Account.findOne({
                    userId: req.user.id,
                    institutionId: institution_id
                  })
                    .then(account => {
                      if (account) {
                        console.log("Account already exists");
                      } else {
                        const newAccount = new Account({
                          userId: userId,
                          publicToken: PUBLIC_TOKEN,
                          accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
                          itemId: ITEM_ID,
                          institutionId: institution_id,
                          institutionName: name
                        });

                        // TO:DO fix error, res.json is not a function
                        newAccount.save().then(account => res.json(account));
                      }
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err)); // Mongo Error
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err)); // Plaid Error
            }
          }
        );
    module.exports = router;
```

The `newAccount.save()` executes just fine, but the subsequent `res.json` throws an error. This is the error that I am getting returned. Namely, `res.json is not a function`.

```
[0] (node:23413) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.json is not a function
[0]     at newAccount.save.then.account (/Users/rishi/plaid-auth/routes/api/plaid.js:97:55)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

There are quite a few posts on here with the `res.json is not a function` error, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I am quite confused why this error is being thrown since I use the same convention in another part of the app and `res.json` works just fine. See the below example of where `res.json` works.

```
// @route POST api/posts
// @desc Create a post
// @access Private
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validatePostInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    const newPost = new Post({
      text: req.body.text,
      name: req.body.name,
      avatar: req.body.avatar,
      user: req.user.id // current logged in user
    });

    // res.json works just fine
    newPost.save().then(post => res.json(post));
  }
);
```

Comment: Please make sure all your variables are properly declared (using `let`, `const` or `var`). I see a bunch of undeclared variables (`PUBLIC_TOKEN`, `ACCESS_TOKEN`, `ITEM_ID`) that aren't properly declared, which could lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have declared all the described variables in my code.

`var PUBLIC_TOKEN = null;`
`var ACCESS_TOKEN = null;`
`var ITEM_ID = null;`

Will update my question to show that I have done so.

Comment: You're overwriting them with each request, which means that you need to declare them _inside_ the handler, not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this piece of code

```
if (PUBLIC_TOKEN) {
          client
            .exchangePublicToken(PUBLIC_TOKEN)
            .then(res => {
              ACCESS_TOKEN = res.access_token;
```

When you get to execute this line `newAccount.save().then(account => res.json(account));` the res is not longer the one on the function `router.post('/accounts/add', (req, res) => {})`

So, the solution is simple, change the res from the promise **exchangePublicToken** into something else like the example below.

You are naming the parameter from the promise callback the same as the parameter on the callback from the router.post above

```
if (PUBLIC_TOKEN) {
          client
            .exchangePublicToken(PUBLIC_TOKEN)
            .then(exchangeResponse => {
              ACCESS_TOKEN = exchangeResponse.access_token;
```

Comment: Do you mean simply renaming the res from the promise? e.g. `newAccount.save().then(account => response.json(account));` ?

If I do that, I get the following error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: Yes, and don’r forget every instance bellow, but you have res, not response

Comment: I am still getting the `ReferenceError: response is not defined` after changing it to `newAccount.save().then(account => response.json(account));`. I do not have any instances below this line that reference either `res` or `response`. Sorry for my confusion, but can you clarify a bit more if you know why I am getting the `response is not defined` error?

Comment: Ok, I get it, you get all the way down to your last promise, that line should be `newAccount.save().then(account => res.json(account));` , I changed my answer a little bit to make it more clear

Comment: The change you recommended in changing res from the exchangePublicToken worked! Thanks so much for your help.